# Order Array Results

Tags: php, arrays

My array will only contain a specific set of characters. However these characters could appear in the array in any order.

I want to rearrange this array so they are always in the same order.

Is this possible as some times the array will contain 1 entry other times upto 4 entries possibly more.

The characters that could appear in the array will be `() ^ & ! #`
But I will have no idea what order until the form is submitted.

Ideally I always want them to be in the following order :

```
!  # ^  &  ()
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible, but PHP makes it a lot harder than in most languages.

Comment: I don't know what the form looks like, but perhaps you could use an array there and assign fixed keys. That way they will always be in the same order **and** always have the same key.

Comment: How would I assign fixed keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
// establish the sort order
$order = array("!","#", "^", "&", "(",")");

// usort with indexes of $orderArray
usort($arr, function($a, $b) use($order) {
      $aIdx = array_search($a, $order);
      $bIdx = array_search($b, $order);
      return $aIdx - $bIdx;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of the built in PHP sort functions, depending on your requirements.

Probably the two you would most be interested in are

- [asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) - Sort an array and maintain index association
- [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) - This function sorts an array. Elements will be arranged from lowest to highest when this function has completed.

Though, there are quite a few others - See [Sorting Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) from Php Manual

Or, alternatively, if the resulting sort order does not match what you are desiring, you could use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), which allows you to define a custom sort function

Something like this should work

```
  $arrayToSort = array('#','&','()','^','!');
  $order = array( '!', '#', '^', '&', '()');

  function compare($a,$b) {
    global $order;
   $indexa = array_search($a,$order);
   $indexb = array_search($b,$order);
   return ($indexa < $indexb) ? -1 : 1;
  }

  usort($arrayToSort, $compare);
```

Comment: This is functionally identical to my method. Pros for your method over mine, a little more easy to read. Pros for my method can live in a function without cluttering global namespace. Also does not use the global keyword.

Comment: Thanks how do I use this. Is it compatible with php 4 ?
The network device I am running this on only supports php 4 !

Comment: Totally agree.. I was editing mine as you posted.. I like your code. It looks much much cleaner. Double plus for use of anonymous function.

Also, yeh asort, usort both work in php 4.